# Discrepancy in thermostat display temperatures

Tags: hvac

On the second floor of our house there are two thermostats on opposite sides of a narrow hallway. One controls the baseboard heat and on the other side of the wall it is on is a room. The other controls the a/c and on the other side of the wall it is on is the attic and the a/c unit. The displayed temperature of the two thermostats had always agreed very closely but recently a new a/c unit was installed (not turned on yet) and since then the a/c thermostat consistently reads two degrees higher than the heat thermostat. I could understand if it were a hot, sunny day and the attic was hotter than the interior of the house, but the display discrepancy is there even in cool mornings, e.g., 72 vs 70. I'm just curious as to why this is happening. Thanks.

Comment: Is the ac thermostat new?

Comment: Assuming that the temps at each thermostat are the same (did you check that??) then at least one of them is incorrect.  Get an independent thermometer, a good one, and check to see which one is at fault.

Comment: The a/c thermostat is not new. It is the one that was there with the previous a/c unit, which was a different brand.

Comment: As the thermostats are wall mounted it may not be so easy to test with an independent thermometer at the same locations, but I'll think about how I might do that.

Comment: Get yourself one of those handheld infrared temperature sensors and check.

Comment: This is funny - I have a small digital thermometer on a stand. When I realized the stand was removable, I in turn placed it right on top of each thermostat for enough time to have it adapt to its new location. What happened was that when as usual one thermostat read 70 and the other read 72, the thermometer read 71 at both locations.

Comment: Perhaps the AC installer re-calibrated the thermostat to ensure good functioning of the new AC?

Answer (score 0):

Having thermostats read slightly different values is quite normal. Mechanical thermostats almost always have an adjustment for this, some digital thermostats also have a calibration procedure but not all.

When I set up temp a temp controllers I use ice point hot point (ice bath and boiling water) as my standard then adjust the controller. I would check your thermostats if they both have adjustments a reference may be needed, or set both to the same value usually the swing from heating to cooling is not enough to have an error once they are set the same at room temp.

The only to get them exact is with a reference that is calibrated but to tell the truth for a home +- 2/3 degrees is below the differential from heating to cooling if not adjustments will need to be made.

Comment: "Having thermostats read slightly different values is quite normal." Understood, but the odd thing here is that these two always agreed closely. It's only with the install of the new  a/c unit that there is a 2 degree discrepancy. Could it have to do with some incompatibility of the thermostat from one a/c brand with another brand's a/c unit?

Comment: The wall could be warmer on one side and the other side is cooler in the hallway. The thermocouple/ thermistor / RTD or what ever is being used to measure the temp is in the controller, all the ones I have checked out have on board voltage regulation there is a possibility the was a voltage shift not an incompatibility issue,  a calibration issue. You just got lucky they were so close to start with.